# Datamapper can't update password token

Tags: ruby, sql-update, datamapper

I have a `user` model

```
class User
  include Datamapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :password_token, String

  def generate_token
   self.password_token = SecureRandom.hex
    self.save
   end
end
```

and this controller route:

```
post '/users/token_sent' do
 user = User.first(email: params[:email])
   if user
     user.generate_token 
   end
 redirect('index')
end
```

I would like the `password_token` property to be changed to the `SecureRandom.hex` instance when the user fills in an email to recover their password from the post route.

The method does not update the `password_token` to the Users database.

Answer (score 0):

In this method:

```
   def generate_token
     self.password_token = SecureRandom.hex
     self.save
   end
```

You're calling `self.save`, which isn't guaranteed to succeed.

If you want to know why it's failing to save, use `save!` instead.